# Find out if query exceeds arbitrary limit using ROWNUM?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, rownum

I have a stored proc in Oracle, and we're limiting the number of records with ROWNUM based on a parameter. However, we also have a requirement to know whether the search result count exceeded the arbitrary limit (even though we're only passing data up to the limit; searches can return a lot of data, and if the limit is exceeded a user may want to refine their query.)

The limit's working well, but I'm attempting to pass an OUT value as a flag to signal when the maximum results were exceeded. My idea for this was to get the count of the inner table and compare it to the count of the outer select query (with ROWNUM) but I'm not sure how I can get that into a variable. Has anyone done this before? Is there any way that I can do this without selecting everything twice?

Thank you.

EDIT: For the moment, I am actually doing two identical selects - one for the count only, selected into my variable, and one for the actual records. I then pass back the comparison of the base result count to my max limit parameter. This means two selects, which isn't ideal. Still looking for an answer here.

Comment: Do you need the actual number, or just that it was higher than your limit?

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of @AlexPoole and allowing limit + 1 rows. If you're already tagging the rows with a rownum value then you could add a sort on `case rownum > limit then 0 else 1 end` and just discard the first row when necessary. Perhaps an extra row is better than an extra column. I'm not sure if the extra sort is a problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a nested subquery:

```
select id, case when max_count > 3 then 'Exceeded' else 'OK' end as flag
from (
 select id, rn, max(rn) over () as max_count
 from (
    select id, rownum as rn
    from t
  )
  where rownum <= 4
)
where rownum <= 3;
```

The inner level is your actual query (which you probably have filters and an order-by clause in really). The middle later restricts to your actual limit + 1, which still allows Oracle to optimise using a stop key, and uses an analytic count over that inner result set to see if you got a fourth record (without requiring a scan of all matching records). And the outer layer restricts to your original limit.

With a sample table with 10 rows, this gets:

```
        ID FLAG    
---------- --------
         1 Exceeded 
         2 Exceeded 
         3 Exceeded
```

If the inner query had a filter that returned fewer rows, say:

```
select id, rownum as rn
from t
where id < 4
```

it would get:

```
        ID FLAG    
---------- --------
         1 OK       
         2 OK       
         3 OK
```

Of course for this demo I haven't done any ordering so you would get indeterminate results. And from your description you would use your variable instead of 3, and (your variable + 1) instead of 4.

Comment: Yeesh, nested madness! The solution makes sense, but the problem remains - if I'm selecting this into a cursor, I can't easily get at the original count (unless I iterate over the cursor and lose results, which I can't do).

Comment: @jedd.ahyoung - you can't return the flag column in the cursor, and have the caller (application?) decide what do do as it consumes the result set? Rather than having a separate out parameter? You can't peek into the cursor unfortunately.

Comment: @jedd.ahyoung - the only other thing you could really do is select into a collection, look at the value in the collection, and then open your cursor by selecting from that; but you'd need a schema-level (not PL/SQL) collection type based on an object that has fields matching the column you're selecting, plus the flag column, which is messy; and will use extra memory, though your limit maybe means that won't be much of a problem.

Comment: I suppose another option is to return up to 4 rows (your variable plus one) rows, and have the caller keep count as consumes the resultset; if it gets a successful fetch after the limit, it can discard that row and set its own 'exceeded’ flag. But that's moving the logic of the check to the caller, which isn't what you wanted, I suppose.

Comment: Yeah, the caller check is actually what we're doing now, and I'm looking for a better way to make it work. It seems like this should be something handled by the DB.

Comment: And yeah, I guess I could actually return the flag column, but I don't think I'd want to add that field to all of the entities that use that feature. The reason for the out parameter is that it's a separation of concerns; the flag in the out parameter, and the data in the cursor.

Comment: Well, as it turns out, we went back to the caller check model. There wasn't really a better way, as it turns out, without invoking a lot of performance issues. One of my coworkers thought of using `sql%rowcount` to get the value, but as we're passing into a cursor, that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a column to the query:

```
select * from (
  select . . . , count(*) over () as numrows
  from . . .
  where . . .
) where rownum <= 1000;
```

And then report `numrows` as the size of the final result set.

Comment: If the `WHERE` clause has a `rownum <= x` clause, `numrows` will be `x` even if the result would otherwise exceed x.

Comment: @JustinCave It should depend on whether the count is in the inner select or the outer select. The problem here is that since I'm putting all of this into a cursor, I can't easily use the count value here.

Comment: @JustinCave . . . That was my understanding of what the OP wanted.

Comment: That should do it. The query will only return 1000 rows, but will have an extra column "numrows" which you can use to determine if the result was truncated or not.

Answer (score 1):

In my application I do a very simple approach. I do the normal SELECT and when the number of returned rows is equal to the limit then the client application shows `LIMIT reached` message, because is it very likely that my query would return more rows in case you would not limit the result.

Of course, when the number of rows is **exactly** the limit then this is a wrong indication. However, in my application the limit is set mainly for performance reasons by end-user, a typical limit is "1000 rows" or "10000 rows", for example.

In my case this solution is fully sufficient - and it is simple.

**Update:**

Are you aware of the [row_limiting_clause](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#BABHFGAA)? It was introduced in Oracle 12.1

For example this query

```
SELECT employee_id, last_name
  FROM employees
  ORDER BY employee_id
  OFFSET 5 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

will return row 6 to row 16 of the entire result set. It may support you in finding a solution.

Another idea is this one:

```
SELECT employee_id, last_name
FROM employees
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL FROM dual
ORDER BY employee_id NULLS LAST
```

When you get the row where `employee_id IS NULL` then you know you reached the end of your result-set and no further records will arrive.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm constrained by business rules and can't change the requirements. A user must know that the results of their query are truncated and don't represent the complete data set, but they need to see the results anyway.

Comment: Upvote for the `row_limiting_clause`. I believe we're using version 11, but it's a handy thing to know.

Answer (score 0):

Select the whole thing, then select the count and the data, restricting the number of rows.

```
with  
base as 
(
    select c1, c2, c3
    from table
    where condition 
) 
select (select count(*) from base), c1, c2, c3 
from base
where rownum < 100
```